# Odd Build Failure even after fully deleting and redownloading from git

Tags: build

My QGL fails when building Enterprise.DocumentEngine.Macros.dll as a Master full build.

The error is listed as
Project "C:\git\dev\Enterprise\Product\Documents\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros.cw.csproj" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
CoreClean:
Creating directory "obj\debug".
C:\git\dev\packages\Antlr4.CodeGenerator\build\Antlr4.CodeGenerator.targets(132,5): error AC1000: Unknown build error: The system cannot find the file specified [C:\git\dev\Enterprise\Product\Documents\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros.cw.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\git\dev\Enterprise\Product\Documents\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros\DocumentEngine.Macros.cw.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.

All files listed can be found in those folders.

I restarted my machine to make sure it wasn't a bad cache.
I built in VS 2022 and got the same error on that project.
I deleted the packages and paket-files folder and ran QGL to redownload and encountered the same error.
I deleted the entire dev folder and downloaded again from git and got the same error.
I asked developers and none had issues building this same code.

I can only think it is a missing dependency that I am not aware of that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't mean for this to be public. But in case you were wondering Antlr was failing due to me having an outdated 32bit java install when our dependency moved to 64bit
Antlr couldn't find the dependencies.